# Spring Context Event

Tags: spring

I am currently studying Spring.
While reading a Spring book, I met a part regarding Event.

By using context.publishEvent(..), I could trigger the event.

But I don't know what It's exactly for.

I can use other Method instead of using complicated publishEvent.

Please, tell me. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Events are used to implement publish-subscribe model (or *observer* pattern) where two not-related parts of code must be somehow connected.

Think of the analogy of web applications where servlet container creates http sessions and your code is informed about this using `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`.

Spring uses this mechanism internally. It's much more visible in Spring Security where several parts of the code are informed about e.g., successfull authentication.